# react hooks: remember me checkbox in Login form not working

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, state, onchange

I have a login form functional component built using react-hooks comprising of `userid, password and rememberMe checkbox`.

For some reason, the checkbox is not working as in, when I click on it, it does tick or untick. Which is basically its state is not changing.

`userid, password and rememberMe checkbox` needs to be sent to the backend. That's why I have to couple it with inputs. If it was an independent checkbox than it would have been easy.

I have `handleChange()` for `userid, password` and I have `handleChechbox()` for handling `checkbox`.

Below is the complete code.

```
const Login = (props) => {
      const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        userid: "",
        password: "",
        rememberPassword: false,
      });
      const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
      const { userid, password, rememberPassword } = inputs;
    
      // reset login status
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(loginActions.logout());
      }, []);
    
      function handleChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setInputs((inputs) => ({ ...inputs, [name]: value }));
      }
    
      function handleChechbox(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        console.log("eeeeee check", e.target.type);
        console.log("eeeeee check", e.target.checked);
        console.log("eeeeee check inputs", inputs);
        console.log("eeeeee check inputs remember", inputs.rememberPassword);
        if (e.target.type === "checkbox" && !e.target.checked) {
          setInputs((inputs) => ({ ...inputs, [name]: "" }));
        } else {
          setInputs((inputs) => ({ ...inputs, [name]: value }));
        }
      }
    
      function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setSubmitted(true);
        if (inputs) {
          // get return url from location state or default to home page
          const { from } = location.state || {
            from: { pathname: "/admin/summary" },
          };
          dispatch(loginActions.login(inputs, from));
          // props.history.push("/admin/summary");
        }
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="Login">
          <div className="login-form-container">
            <div className="content">
              <Form className="login-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <InputGroup>
                  <InputGroupAddon
                    className="input-group-addon"
                    addonType="prepend"
                  >
                    <i className="fa fa-user"></i>
                  </InputGroupAddon>
                  <input
                    autoFocus
                    type="email"
                    aria-label="Username"
                    aria-describedby="Username"
                    aria-invalid="false"
                    placeholder="Username or Email"
                    name="userid"
                    value={userid}
                    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
                    className={
                      "form-control" + (submitted && !userid ? " is-invalid" : "")
                    }
                  />
                  {submitted && !userid && (
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">
                      Username or Email is required
                    </div>
                  )}
                </InputGroup>
                <InputGroup>
                  <InputGroupAddon
                    className="input-group-addon"
                    addonType="prepend"
                  >
                    <i className="fa fa-lock"></i>
                  </InputGroupAddon>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    aria-label="password"
                    aria-describedby="password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
                    className={
                      "form-control" + (submitted && !password ? " is-invalid" : "")
                    }
                  />
                  {submitted && !password && (
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">Password is required</div>
                  )}
                </InputGroup>
                <div className="form-actions">
                  <br />
                  <div className="form-check">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      className="form-check-input"
                      id="rememberPassword"
                      name="checkbox"
                      checked={rememberPassword}
                      onChange={(event) => handleChechbox(event)}
                      // required
                    />
                    <label className="form-check-label" for="rememberPassword">
                      Remember me
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Could you put this into a codesanbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading the name attribute which is 'checkbox' not 'rememberPassword'. I'd imagine a simple console log of inputs would reveal you're setting the wrong property name.

Anyway your input is controlled, you don't need to read DOM values since you know that the value is and what it should change to.

```
function handleRememberMeChange(e) {
  setInputs((inputs) => ({ ...inputs, rememberPassword: !inputs.rememberPassword }));
}
```

If you want it to work generically from an attribute then use `id` or change `name` to "rememberPassword". And use `e.target.checked` not `e.target.value`.

Also it's fine to do `onChange={handleChechbox}` instead of `onChange={(event) => handleChechbox(event)}` it's the same thing.